# Query Data Extension with Left Join on All Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am querying a DE and trying to left join _Subscribers on SubscriberKey. I am getting results back from the left side, Master_DE, but nothing is coming back for the Status column. I am wondering if there is something wrong with my SQL? m.SubscriberKey is a text(100) DE field. I also know there should be data coming back because I have verified the matching rows exist.

```
SELECT m.personid, 
       m.[join_date], 
       s.status 
FROM   [master_de] m 
       LEFT JOIN _Subscribers s 
              ON m.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE  [join_date] > Dateadd(d, -7, Getdate()) 
       AND [join_date] < Dateadd(d, Datediff(dd, 0, Getdate()), 0)
```

Comment: When you view your DE properties, what does the relationship to Subs say?  For example, "EmailAddress relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ExactTarget account is an Enterprise account, try prefixing the system data view name with ENT.

```
SELECT ... 
FROM [master_de] m 
LEFT JOIN ENT.[_Subscribers] s 
ON m.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
```

See [this Help article](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) for more information.

Comment: This is the correct answer, however the table name should not be wrapped in brackets. It should be `LEFT JOIN ENT._Subscribers`. It will actually throw an error when you try to save the query.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a Status column on your [master_de] data extension?  What happens if you do a standard JOIN and not use the "Left Join"?  Does this now populate with a status (Text-15 characters)?

```
SELECT m.personid, 
       m.[join_date], 
       s.status 
FROM   [master_de] m 
       JOIN _Subscribers s 
              ON m.SubscriberKey = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE  [join_date] > Dateadd(d, -7, Getdate()) 
       AND [join_date] < Dateadd(d, Datediff(dd, 0, Getdate()), 0)
```